# Trying to toggle visibility of classes with buttons (using Javascript), absolutely nothing works, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set up a page where the visibility of certain elements on a page are toggled by buttons, but for some reason, my code is simply ignored / does absolutely nothing.

I can get this to work when using ID's, but then only the first instance of the ID on the page gets changed while the rest are ignored.  With classes, *nothing happens*.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but I can't figure out what.  Please check below:

```js
function georgianInfo() {
  document.getElementByClassName("georgian").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementByClassName("international").style.display = "none";
}

function internationalInfo() {
  document.getElementByClassName("georgian").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementByClassName("international").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.georgian {
  display: none;
}

.international {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form><input type="button" onClick="georgianInfo()" value="georgian students"></form>

<form><input type="button" onClick="internationalInfo()" value="international students"></form>

<h4 class="margin-rmv">Admissions Information</h4>

<h5 class="georgian">Georgian Students Admissions Information</h5>

<h5 class="international">International Students Admissions Information</h5>
```

Refer codepen: https://codepen.io/escapetomars/pen/vxBLgg

Answer (score 3):

Change the spelling of `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Also, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array/list of elements. So you have to refer it with the correct index.

Refer code:

```js
function georgianInfo() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("georgian")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("international")[0].style.display = "none";
}

function internationalInfo() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("georgian")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("international")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.georgian {
  display: none;
}

.international {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="tab-menu" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form><input type="button" onClick="georgianInfo()" value="for georgian students"></form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form><input type="button" onClick="internationalInfo()" value="for international students"></form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h4 class="margin-rmv">Admissions Information</h4>

<h5 class="georgian">Georgian Students Admissions Information</h5>

<h5 class="international">International Students Admissions Information</h5>
```

I would suggest you to go through the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) regarding `Document.getElementsByClassName` for a better understanding of the construct.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That fixed it, and gives me a better understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Change functions as:

```
    function georgianInfo() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("georgian")[0].style.display = "block";
      document.getElementsByClassName("international")[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    function internationalInfo() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("georgian")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("international")[0].style.display = "block";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct method is document.getElementsByClassName and as the name suggests it returns an array of items. So if you have to apply anything on these elements you need to iterate over that array and then apply something on each element or you can pick a particular element using array indexes.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0]; // assuming you have at least one matching element.
element.style.display = 'none';
```

Here is the link to updated codepen

http://codepen.io/vibhanshu/pen/EWYNMb

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important difference between `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`. Id is unique and there is only one element by `id="abc"`. So `getElementById('abc')` gets the element and you can change its styles. Some browsers if you have repeated id, will get you the first one.

But `getElementsByClassName` is different. There could be multiple elements `class="abc"`. So `getElementsByClassName` gives you a collection, and you can not change the style of a collection by the way you did. And as mentioned in another answers you need to select an element from the collection to change its styles.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("georgian")[0].style.display = "block";
```