# How do I change multiple elements with same class name using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42389937/2803565) - I want to use a button to show / hide multiple elements with the same class name using JS, yet it appears that I can only change the first element with a certain class name, and all further elements with the same class on the page are ignored.

How do I fix this?

```js
 function designInfo() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("design")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("it")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("other")[0].style.display = "none";
 }

 function itInfo() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("design")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("it")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("other")[0].style.display = "none";
 }
 
 function allInfo() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("design")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("it")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("other")[0].style.display = "block";
 }
```

```css
    .it {}
    .design {}
    .other {}

    .indent {
      margin: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="designInfo()">show design stuff</button>
    <button onclick="itInfo()">show IT stuff</button>
    <button onclick="allInfo()">show all</button>

    <div class="indent">

       <div class="it">• boring IT stuff</div>
       <div class="design">• cool design stuff</div>
       <div class="it">• it stuff and things</div>
       <div class="design">• design stuff</div>
       <div class="it">• it stuff and more</div>
       <div class="other">• more it stuff</div>
       <div class="other">• it stuff</div>
  
    </div>
```

Comment: Select all elements -> for each -> do stuff.

Comment: Select all elements?  I thought that's what: getElementsByClassName would do, but I guess it doesn't...

Comment: Using `[0]` after your selection will get the first node and only the first node.

Comment: "Select all elements" == `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Or, do it _properly_, and don’t manipulate style values directly, but set a class only (separation of concerns). And if you make use of the descendant selector, you only need to set it _once_ on a common ancestor element, instead of for each individual element.

Comment: chazsolo, without [0], absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: @escapetomars agreed, just pointing out part of the problem - not trying to answer the question in a comment.

Comment: why you don't use Jquery?

Comment: weedoze beat me to show the implementation, but anyway here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrBZrr PS: this uses some features of es2015.

Comment: did you check my answer? what's your feedback?

Answer (score 14):

You need to use a for-loop over all items you get from `document.getElementsByClassName()` method as in following snippet:

```js
function setDisplay(className, displayValue) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.display = displayValue;
  }
}

function designInfo() {
  setDisplay("design", "block");
  setDisplay("it", "none");
  setDisplay("other", "none");
}

function itInfo() {
  setDisplay("design", "none");
  setDisplay("it", "block");
  setDisplay("other", "none");
}

function allInfo() {
  setDisplay("design", "block");
  setDisplay("it", "block");
  setDisplay("other", "block");
}
```

```css
.it {}
.design {}
.other {}

.indent {
  margin: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="designInfo()">show design stuff</button>
<button onclick="itInfo()">show IT stuff</button>
<button onclick="allInfo()">show all</button>

<div class="indent">

   <div class="it">• boring IT stuff</div>
   <div class="design">• cool design stuff</div>
   <div class="it">• it stuff and things</div>
   <div class="design">• design stuff</div>
   <div class="it">• it stuff and more</div>
   <div class="other">• more it stuff</div>
   <div class="other">• it stuff</div>

</div>
```

---

**Update**
Also, it could be written with less code as below:

```js
function filter(designDisp, itDisp, otherDisp) {
  setDisplay("design", designDisp);
  setDisplay("it", itDisp);
  setDisplay("other", otherDisp);
}

function setDisplay(className, displayValue) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.display = (displayValue? "block" : "none");
  }
}
```

```css
.it {}
.design {}
.other {}

.indent {
  margin: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="filter(1,0,0)">show design stuff</button>
<button onclick="filter(0,1,0)">show IT stuff</button>
<button onclick="filter(1,1,1)">show all</button>

<div class="indent">

   <div class="it">• boring IT stuff</div>
   <div class="design">• cool design stuff</div>
   <div class="it">• it stuff and things</div>
   <div class="design">• design stuff</div>
   <div class="it">• it stuff and more</div>
   <div class="other">• more it stuff</div>
   <div class="other">• it stuff</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to do this with classes that show/hide the element. Your problem is you are using the first index [0] of the matched array. You need to loop through each element in the array to manipulate the element.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');

els.forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

You can do the same with `el.classList.remove(className);` to remove a class

Note: forEach is an ECMAScript 5 function

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements. You have to iterate them and update their style one by one

```js
var elements = {
  design: document.getElementsByClassName("design"),
  it: document.getElementsByClassName("it"),
  other: document.getElementsByClassName("other")
};

function toggle(type) {
  Object.keys(elements).forEach(function(key) {
    var els = elements[key];
    var state = "none";
    if (key === type) state = "block";
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      els[i].style.display = state;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.indent {
  margin: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle('design')">show design stuff</button>
<button onclick="toggle('it')">show IT stuff</button>
<button onclick="toggle('other')">show all</button>

<div class="indent">
  <div class="it">• boring IT stuff</div>
  <div class="design">• cool design stuff</div>
  <div class="it">• it stuff and things</div>
  <div class="design">• design stuff</div>
  <div class="it">• it stuff and more</div>
  <div class="other">• more it stuff</div>
  <div class="other">• it stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @escapetomars Wait a sec I will try to make it better

Answer (score 0):

**You're half way there:**

Use this function and pass through the class name and either 'block' or 'none'

```
function toggle(className, state){
    elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for(var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
        elementArray[i].style.display = state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, made together with `jQuery`. I've provided just one function, which accepts an argument, which is the name of the elements you want to leave in the list.

```js
var elems = $('.indent').children('div');

function filter(v) {
  elems.filter(function() {
    $(this).show();
    if (!$(this).hasClass(v) && v) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.indent {
  margin: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="filter('design')">show design stuff</button>
<button onclick="filter('it')">show IT stuff</button>
<button onclick="filter()">show all</button>

<div class="indent">

  <div class="it">• boring IT stuff</div>
  <div class="design">• cool design stuff</div>
  <div class="it">• it stuff and things</div>
  <div class="design">• design stuff</div>
  <div class="it">• it stuff and more</div>
  <div class="other">• more it stuff</div>
  <div class="other">• it stuff</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var X = document.querySelectorAll(".className");

for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {

    X[i].style.cssProperty = someNumber + "unitType";

}
```

Example: `X[i].style.width = 100 + "%";`

**If you want it to apply random integers:**

```
var X = document.querySelectorAll(".className");

for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * someNumber);

    X[i].style.cssProperty = rand + "unitType";

}
```