# Using class instead of id in JS to do an action

Tags: javascript, function

First, sorry I'm not good with javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="Comment-ID">
   <p class="comment-content">...</p>
 </div>
```

The javascript: (Edit: Added the whole code)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function autoloadmore() {
  var loadmoreClass = document.getElementsByClassName(&quot;loadmore&quot;)[0];
  var loadmoreChild = loadmoreClass.querySelector(&#39;a&#39;)

  if (loadmoreClass) {
    loadmoreChild.click();
  }
}
//<![CDATA[
function InsertarImagenVideo(id) {
var IDelemento = document.getElementById(id),
sustituir = IDelemento.innerHTML;
sustituir = sustituir.replace(/\[img\](.[^\]]*)\[\/img\]/ig, "<img class='img-comentarios' src='$1'\/>");
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = sustituir;
}
//]]>



window.onload = function() {
  autoloadmore();
  setTimeout(function(){
    InsertarImagenVideo('Comment-ID');
  },3000);
};
</script>
```

"InsertarImagenVideo" replaces some text inside with an image. Instead of using it on "Comment-ID", I want to use it on "Comment-class".

Note: I can't edit the HTML.

I couldn't find anything when I searched, or maybe I didn't know how to look. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Currently you're not using a class *or* an id.  You're passing a string literal to a function.  What that function *does* with that string literal is up to you.  (Or, well, to the author of the function.)  If you want to *change* what that function does with that string literal, you'll need to look at the function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416214/how-do-i-change-multiple-elements-with-same-class-name-using-javascript

Comment: InsertarImagenVideo would have to change....  nothing can be done without altering that code.

Comment: I assume you can edit the Javascript?

Comment: Of course I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select an element by class:

Update this line:
`var IDelemento = document.getElementById(id),`

to `var IDelemento = document.querySelector(id),`

and pass the class [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to your method `InsertarImagenVideo`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    InsertarImagenVideo('.comment-content');
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to insert an image into the `<p class="comment-content">...</p>` element by grabbing the parent `<div id="Comment-ID">`.

I'm assuming that you need to grab the unique `id` to then access the inner `<p>` element to replace the existing text with an image. This code grabs the unique `id` element, then grabs the first `<p>` tag using `.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]`. One thing I did add is a proper image load script to update the `<p>` tag with the image once it has been loaded (maybe this removes the need for that `setTimeout` function you have?).

```
let classElement = document.getElementById("Comment-ID").getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
let imageObject = new Image();
imageObject.src = `https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/1-14442_smiley-face-png-smiley-png.png`;

imageObject.onload = function() {
    classElement.innerHTML = `<img id="myImg" src="${imageObject.src}" />`; 
  let imageElement = document.getElementById(`myImg`);
  imageElement.width = 100;
  imageElement.height = 100;
};
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/51vdga74/77/) of the upper code in action.

Hope this helps :)